# Parse Webhook: Get Data Appended to Webhook URL

Tags: parse-platform, redirect, parse-cloud-code, webhooks, square-connect

I'm doing OAuth2 to integrate Square and my app which uses Parse as its backend.

My issue is that when Square calls the redirect uri, it directs the user to a subdomain I created in Parse with the authorization code appended to the subdomain uri.  **I need to extract this authorization code from the uri, but do not know how.**  Parse Cloud Code is needed to do this.

I believe I need to create a Webhook URL in Cloud Code and then extract the data appended to the URL, the base of which is the subdomain URL.  Steps outlining the process, code examples and links to helpful documentation would be much appreciated.

Furthermore, once I figure this out, I need to have my web browser jump the user back to the app that brought up Square initially once this redirect URL is called.  Not sure how to do this and haven't found things that make sense.  Tips, recommendations and links would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to go would be create an independent route on the server that handles all your communication with square. I mean something that doesn't have Parse.
You can now still communicate with Parse from this route and make queries but the best thing is to just create a separate route that id devoid of parse.

Because even if you can find a way to implement via triggers or hooks, Parse might not be able to give you a flexible implementation that can be extensible over time.

Comment: I only know iOS unfortunately so I would have to get another solution towards the end of the summer when my friend I'm working with is good enough at other things to do so.  So I need to figure something simple out which will probably be in Parse for now.  Do you know if one can call a webhook if there is stuff appended to the webhook's base URL?  Also, do you know if one can extract that information appended to the webhook's base URL? @ribads